# Why these two C pointers set to NULL after one line code?

Tags: c

Here are the codes I do not understand and never met before.
only one line of codes change rvalue pointer and set it to NULL

```
if ((*v)->r != NULL)
            printf("WTF r != NULL r %p p %p p->l %p (*v) %p \n",(*v)->r,(*v)->p,(*v)->p->l,(*v));

        (*v)->p->l = (*v)->r;
if ((*v)->r == NULL)
            printf("WTF r == NULL r %p p %p p->l %p (*v) %p \n",(*v)->r,(*v)->p,(*v)->p->l,(*v));
```

both messages were printed. 
r and l were set to NULL.
It is very strange.

below are all the codes I try to debug.
You may compile and run it.
Thank you very much!!!
It is a Avl tree

AVL_tree.h

```
#if !defined AVL_TREE_H
#define AVL_TREE_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
struct vertex{
   int data;
   long height;
   struct vertex *l,*r,*p;
};
void insert(struct vertex** root, int data);
void* find(struct vertex* root, int data);
void clear_tree(struct vertex** root);
void print_tree(struct vertex* root);
#endif
```

AVL_tree.c

```
#include"./AVL_tree.h"
static long
max(long a, long b)
{
return (((a) > (b)) ? a : b);
}
static long
balance_factor(struct vertex *v)
{
if (v->l == NULL && v->r == NULL)
    return 0;
else if (v->l == NULL)
    return (-1) - v->r->height;
else if (v->r == NULL)
    return v->l->height - (-1);

return (v->l->height - v->r->height);
}
static void
update_height(struct vertex *v)
{
if (v->l == NULL
    && v->r == NULL) {
    v->height = 0;
    return;
} else if (v->l == NULL) {
    v->height = v->r->height + 1;
    return;
} else if (v->r == NULL) {
    v->height = v->l->height + 1;
    return;
}
v->height = max(v->l->height, v->r->height) + 1;
}
static void
right_rotate(struct vertex **v)
{

if ((*v)->p != NULL) {
    if ((*v)->p->l == (*v))
        (*v)->p->l = (*v)->l;
    else
        (*v)->p->r = (*v)->l;
}
struct vertex  *tmp = (*v)->l->r;
(*v)->l->r = (*v);
(*v)->l->p = (*v)->p;
(*v)->p = (*v)->l;
(*v)->l = tmp;
if (tmp != NULL)
    tmp->p = (*v);

update_height(*v);
(*v) = (*v)->p;
update_height(*v);
}
static void
left_rotate(struct vertex **v)
{

if ((*v)->r == NULL)
    printf("1 r == NULL\n");

if ((*v)->p != NULL) {
    printf(" p is not NULL\n");
    if ((*v)->p->r == (*v))
        (*v)->p->r = (*v)->r;
    else if ((*v)->p->l == (*v)) {
        printf("p's l  == v\n");

        if ((*v)->r != NULL)
            printf("WTF r != NULL r %p p %p p->l %p (*v) %p \n",(*v)->r,(*v)->p,(*v)->p->l,(*v));

        (*v)->p->l = (*v)->r;
        if ((*v)->r == NULL)
            printf("WTF r == NULL r %p p %p p->l %p (*v) %p \n",(*v)->r,(*v)->p,(*v)->p->l,(*v));

    } else {
        printf("error case \n");
    }
}
printf("get there before\n");

if ((*v)->r == NULL)
    printf("r == NULL\n");

struct vertex  *tmp = (*v)->r->l;
printf("get there after\n");
(*v)->r->l = (*v);
printf("get there \n");
(*v)->r->p = (*v)->p;
(*v)->p = (*v)->r;
(*v)->r = tmp;
printf("get there \n");
if (tmp != NULL)
    tmp->p = (*v);
printf("get there \n");
update_height(*v);
(*v) = (*v)->p;
update_height(*v);
}

static void
insert_fixup(struct vertex *new_vertex)
{
while ((new_vertex->p != NULL)
       && ((new_vertex->height + 1) > new_vertex->p->height)) {
    update_height(new_vertex->p);
    new_vertex = new_vertex->p;
    if (balance_factor(new_vertex) == 2) {
        if (balance_factor(new_vertex->l) == -1) {
            printf("double left right rotating \n");
            left_rotate(&new_vertex->l);
        }
        right_rotate(&new_vertex);
        return;
    } else if (balance_factor(new_vertex) == -2) {
        if (balance_factor(new_vertex->r) == 1) {
            printf("double right left rotating \n");
            right_rotate(&new_vertex->r);
            printf("double right rotating finish\n");
        }
        left_rotate(&new_vertex);
        return;
    }
}
}
void
insert(struct vertex **tree, int data)
{
struct vertex  *new_vertex = malloc(sizeof(struct vertex));
new_vertex->data = data;
new_vertex->height = 0;
new_vertex->l = NULL;
new_vertex->r = NULL;
new_vertex->p = NULL;

if (tree == NULL)
    return;
else if (*tree == NULL) {
    *tree = new_vertex;
    return;
}
struct vertex  *root = *tree;
while (1) {
    if (root->data < data) {
        if (root->r != NULL)
            root = root->r;
        else {
            root->r = new_vertex;
            new_vertex->p = root;
            break;
        }
    } else {
        if (root->l != NULL)
            root = root->l;
        else {
            root->l = new_vertex;
            new_vertex->p = root;
            break;
        }
    }
}
insert_fixup(new_vertex);
while ((*tree)->p != NULL) {
    (*tree) = (*tree)->p;
}
}
void           *
find(struct vertex *v, int data)
{
while (v != NULL && v->data != data)
    if (v->data < data)
        v = v->r;
    else
        v = v->l;

return v;


}
static void
free_tree(struct vertex *root)
{
if (root->l != NULL)
    free_tree(root->l);
if (root->r != NULL)
    free_tree(root->r);

free(root);
return;
}
void
clear_tree(struct vertex **root)
{
free_tree(*root);
*root = NULL;
}
```

test.c

```
#include"./AVL_tree.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

int main(){

time_t t;
srand(time(&t));
struct vertex* root = NULL;
int i,j,limit = 1000000,incretment = 500000;
printf("starting insert %d elements with increment %d in next round\n",limit,incretment); 
for (j = 0; j <= 100; j++){
  clock_t start,end;
  start = clock();
  for (i = 0; i < limit;i++){
 int random = rand() % 10;
 printf("inserting %d \n",random);
 insert(&root,random);
  }
  end = clock();
  double total = (double)(end - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  printf("%f\n",total);
  clear_tree(&root);
}

}
```

Comment: The behaviour you are seeing is the sort of thing you sometimes see if you have code that returns a pointer to a local variable from a function, and you then try to use (print) the value several times.  The space gets reused as local memory in called functions (e.g. `printf()`) and that changes the value in other variables.

Comment: when calling the memory allocation functions, like `malloc()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: in the `insert()` function,  the check for `tree == NULL` should be done before the call to malloc(), otherwise the pointer to the allocated memory is lost, so can never be passed to `free()` resulting in a memory leak

Comment: for ease of understanding and for readability by us humans, 1) please indent consistently, indent after every opening brace '{', un-indent before every closing brace '}'  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, whjile, do...while, switch, case, default) with a single blank line.  3) please follow the axiiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: the `incretment` variable is only being used in a `printf()` statment, so is pointless

Comment: the posted code, when run, results in a seg fault event. (which you did not mention)

Comment: @Pang,  since you edited the posted code, why did you not format the code for consistent indenting, etc.?  The posted code strongly suggests it is actually 3 different files,  Why did you not indicate that in the editing?

Comment: @user3629249 the bug was narrowed to just one line. I just want to show the problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler after looking at the printing message. (*v)->p->l = (*v)->r is equivalent to (*v)->p = (*v); (*v) = (*v)->r. It is very strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the bug for this codes now. The right/left rotation functions use pointer to pointer. When I pass the parent's l or r pointer to it. It cause a bug inside the function. A better way to improve this code is replace pointer to pointer by just pointer and update pointer by returning value.

Answer (score 2):

### First Pass

When I take your code, add `void` to `int main()` to get it past my compilation options, and reformat the code so it is indented more or less orthodoxly, then I get no compilation warnings.  For that, you have my compliments; very few programs shown on SO need so little editing to get past my default compilation options:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wold-style-definition -Werror -c test.c
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wold-style-definition -Werror -c AVL_tree.c
gcc -g -o avl test.o AVL_tree.o
```

When I then run it under [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/), then I get told:

```
starting insert 1000000 elements with increment 500000 in next round
inserting 0 
inserting 6 
inserting 1 
double right left rotating 
==47254== Invalid read of size 8
==47254==    at 0x100000FB5: right_rotate (AVL_tree.c:54)
==47254==    by 0x10000159E: insert (AVL_tree.c:138)
==47254==    by 0x100001AB6: main (test.c:20)
==47254==  Address 0x18 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==47254== 
==47254== 
==47254== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==47254==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x18
==47254==    at 0x100000FB5: right_rotate (AVL_tree.c:54)
==47254==    by 0x10000159E: insert (AVL_tree.c:138)
==47254==    by 0x100001AB6: main (test.c:20)
```

In your code as formatted, line 54 is the `struct vertex *tmp` line at:

```
        (*v)->p->l = (*v)->l;
    else
        (*v)->p->r = (*v)->l;
}
struct vertex  *tmp = (*v)->l->r;
(*v)->l->r = (*v);
(*v)->l->p = (*v)->p;
(*v)->p = (*v)->l;
(*v)->l = tmp;
if (tmp != NULL)
    tmp->p = (*v);
```

The address 0x18 strongly suggests you have dereferenced a null pointer.  It is a small offset from NULL and on a 64-bit machine, address offset 0x18 corresponds to `r` in the structure, I think.  At any rate, it appears that your code has not taken into account a null pointer somehow.

Another run produced:

```
starting insert 1000000 elements with increment 500000 in next round
inserting 6 
inserting 2 
inserting 3 
double left right rotating 
 p is not NULL
p's l  == v
WTF r != NULL r 0x100aa85d0 p 0x100aa84f0 p->l 0x100aa8560 (*v) 0x100aa8560 
WTF r == NULL r 0x0 p 0x100aa8560 p->l 0x0 (*v) 0x100aa85d0 
get there before
r == NULL
==47387== Invalid read of size 8
==47387==    at 0x100001134: left_rotate (AVL_tree.c:99)
==47387==    by 0x10000157F: insert (AVL_tree.c:128)
==47387==    by 0x100001AB6: main (test.c:20)
==47387==  Address 0x10 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==47387== 
==47387== 
==47387== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==47387==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x10
==47387==    at 0x100001134: left_rotate (AVL_tree.c:99)
==47387==    by 0x10000157F: insert (AVL_tree.c:128)
==47387==    by 0x100001AB6: main (test.c:20)
```

Again, that suggests a null pointer dereference.

I recommend adding a bunch of assertions checking that all the pointers you think can't be null actually aren't null — some of them, it appears, are in fact null.

I also recommend using a different `main()` program.  Keep the current one for later, when things are mostly working and you want to stress test the code.  For now, you want a simple deterministic program.  You should try inserting the sequences `0, 6, 1` and `6, 2, 3` and see whether you get a crash.  If so, you can debug them, and look for parallel problems in the code.  (Another, longer sequence that crashed at the same point as the second crash was `3, 4, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 7, 5, 1, 7`; and another was `4,  5,  4,  3,  2,  2,  4,  2,  5,  0,  2`.)

I note that your header should not itself include any other headers.  A header should only include those other headers that are necessary to make the code within compilable on its own.  Your structure doesn't use any features defined in `<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>` or `<assert.h>`, so none of those headers should be included there.  You don't actually have any assertions in the posted code, but the other two headers are needed in the implementation code and `<stdio.h>` is needed in the test code; but they should included directly.

Note that when debugging with assertions, make independent assertions.  If you write:

```
assert((*v) != NULL && (*v)->r != NULL);
```

and the assertion fires, you can't tell which of the two conditions failed.  Use independent assertions:

```
assert((*v) != NULL);
assert((*v)->r != NULL);
```

but sequence them like that — not the reverse.  This tells you which of the two conditions is erroneous.

### Second Pass

I added some instrumentation to your code in  `AVL_tree.c`, using the formatting available in `<inttypes.h>` to format pointers according to my prejudices, rather than letting the `%p` format do it for me (it prints null pointers as `0x0` instead of using a similar width to other pointers — not what I want for readable output; using `%.9` is a hack that works on this 64-bit machine [Mac OS X 10.11.3, GCC 5.3.0]; stack addresses are about 12 hex digits wide, so it is potentially flaky formatting).  And I created a minimal deterministic test program, `avl2.c`.

#### `AVL_tree.c`

```
#include "AVL_tree.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void dump_vertex(const char *tag, struct vertex *v)
{
    if (v == NULL)
        printf("%s: data  ; height  ; v = 0x%.9" PRIXPTR "\n", tag, (uintptr_t)v);
    else
        printf("%s: data %d; height %ld; v = 0x%.9" PRIXPTR ", l = 0x%.9"
               PRIXPTR ", r = 0x%.9" PRIXPTR ", p = 0x%.9" PRIXPTR "\n",
               tag, v->data, v->height, (uintptr_t)v, (uintptr_t)v->l,
               (uintptr_t)v->r, (uintptr_t)v->p);
}

static void dump_tree_inorder_notag(const struct vertex *v)
{
    if (v != NULL)
    {
        dump_tree_inorder_notag(v->l);
        printf("data %d; height %ld; v = 0x%.9" PRIXPTR ", l = 0x%.9" PRIXPTR
               ", r = 0x%.9" PRIXPTR ", p = 0x%.9" PRIXPTR "\n",
               v->data, v->height, (uintptr_t)v, (uintptr_t)v->l,
               (uintptr_t)v->r, (uintptr_t)v->p);
        dump_tree_inorder_notag(v->r);
    }
}

static void dump_tree_inorder(const char *tag, struct vertex *v)
{
    printf("-->> %s: (root 0x%.9" PRIXPTR ")\n", tag, (uintptr_t)v);
    dump_tree_inorder_notag(v);
    printf("<<-- %s:\n", tag);
}

static inline long
max(long a, long b)
{
    return(((a) > (b)) ? a : b);
}

static long
balance_factor(struct vertex *v)
{
    assert(v != NULL);
    if (v->l == NULL && v->r == NULL)
        return 0;
    else if (v->l == NULL)
        return (-1) - v->r->height;
    else if (v->r == NULL)
        return v->l->height - (-1);

    return(v->l->height - v->r->height);
}

static void
update_height(struct vertex *v)
{
    assert(v != NULL);
    if (v->l == NULL && v->r == NULL)
    {
        v->height = 0;
        return;
    }
    else if (v->l == NULL)
    {
        v->height = v->r->height + 1;
        return;
    }
    else if (v->r == NULL)
    {
        v->height = v->l->height + 1;
        return;
    }
    v->height = max(v->l->height, v->r->height) + 1;
}

static void
right_rotate(struct vertex **v)
{
    if ((*v)->p != NULL)
    {
        if ((*v)->p->l == (*v))
            (*v)->p->l = (*v)->l;
        else
            (*v)->p->r = (*v)->l;
    }
    struct vertex  *tmp = (*v)->l->r;
    (*v)->l->r = (*v);
    (*v)->l->p = (*v)->p;
    (*v)->p = (*v)->l;
    (*v)->l = tmp;
    if (tmp != NULL)
        tmp->p = (*v);

    update_height(*v);
    (*v) = (*v)->p;
    update_height(*v);
}

static void
left_rotate(struct vertex **v)
{
    assert(v != NULL);
    assert(*v != NULL);
    dump_vertex("-->> left_rotate", *v);
    if ((*v)->r == NULL)
        printf("1 r == NULL\n");

    if ((*v)->p != NULL)
    {
        printf("p is not NULL\n");
        if ((*v)->p->r == (*v))
        {
            (*v)->p->r = (*v)->r;
        }
        else if ((*v)->p->l == (*v))
        {
            printf("p's l  == v\n");
            dump_vertex("LR1 -  current node", *v);
            dump_vertex("LR1 -   parent node", (*v)->p);
            dump_vertex("LR1 -  parent  left", (*v)->p->l);
            dump_vertex("LR1 - current right", (*v)->r);
            dump_tree_inorder("LR1 - tree from parent", (*v)->p);

            //if ((*v)->r != NULL)
                //printf("WTF r != NULL r %p p %p p->l %p (*v) %p\n", (*v)->r, (*v)->p, (*v)->p->l, (*v));

            printf("Assign (*v)->r (0x%.9" PRIXPTR ") to (*v)->p->l (0x%.9" PRIXPTR ")\n",
                (uintptr_t)(*v)->r, (uintptr_t)(*v)->p->l);
            (*v)->p->l = (*v)->r;

            dump_vertex("LR2 -  current node", *v);
            dump_vertex("LR2 -   parent node", (*v)->p);
            dump_vertex("LR2 -  parent  left", (*v)->p->l);
            dump_vertex("LR2 - current right", (*v)->r);
            // At this point, we don't have a tree
            //dump_tree_inorder("LR2 - tree from parent", (*v)->p);

            //if ((*v)->r == NULL)
                //printf("WTF r == NULL r %p p %p p->l %p (*v) %p\n", (*v)->r, (*v)->p, (*v)->p->l, (*v));
        }
        else
        {
            printf("error case\n");
        }
    }
    else
        dump_vertex("(*v)->p == NULL", (*v)->p);
    printf("get there before\n");

    if ((*v)->r == NULL)
        printf("r == NULL\n");

    assert((*v)->r != NULL);

    struct vertex  *tmp = (*v)->r->l;
    printf("get there after\n");
    (*v)->r->l = (*v);
    printf("get there\n");
    (*v)->r->p = (*v)->p;
    (*v)->p = (*v)->r;
    (*v)->r = tmp;
    printf("get there\n");
    if (tmp != NULL)
        tmp->p = (*v);
    printf("get there\n");
    update_height(*v);
    (*v) = (*v)->p;
    update_height(*v);
    dump_vertex("<<-- left_rotate", *v);
}

static void
insert_fixup(struct vertex *new_vertex)
{
    dump_tree_inorder("insert fixup 0", new_vertex);
    while ((new_vertex->p != NULL)
           && ((new_vertex->height + 1) > new_vertex->p->height))
    {
        update_height(new_vertex->p);
        new_vertex = new_vertex->p;
        if (balance_factor(new_vertex) == 2)
        {
            if (balance_factor(new_vertex->l) == -1)
            {
                printf("double left right rotating\n");
                left_rotate(&new_vertex->l);
                printf("double left right rotating finish\n");
            }
            right_rotate(&new_vertex);
            dump_tree_inorder("insert fixup 1", new_vertex);
            return;
        }
        else if (balance_factor(new_vertex) == -2)
        {
            if (balance_factor(new_vertex->r) == 1)
            {
                printf("double right left rotating\n");
                right_rotate(&new_vertex->r);
                printf("double right rotating finish\n");
            }
            left_rotate(&new_vertex);
            dump_tree_inorder("insert fixup 2", new_vertex);
            return;
        }
    }
    dump_tree_inorder("insert fixup 3", new_vertex);
}

void
insert(struct vertex **tree, int data)
{
    assert(tree != NULL);
    struct vertex  *new_vertex = malloc(sizeof(struct vertex));
    assert(new_vertex != NULL);
    new_vertex->data = data;
    new_vertex->height = 0;
    new_vertex->l = NULL;
    new_vertex->r = NULL;
    new_vertex->p = NULL;

    if (tree == NULL)
        return;
    else if (*tree == NULL)
    {
        *tree = new_vertex;
        dump_tree_inorder("insert-1", *tree);
        return;
    }
    struct vertex  *root = *tree;
    while (1)
    {
        if (root->data < data)
        {
            if (root->r != NULL)
                root = root->r;
            else
            {
                root->r = new_vertex;
                new_vertex->p = root;
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (root->l != NULL)
                root = root->l;
            else
            {
                root->l = new_vertex;
                new_vertex->p = root;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    insert_fixup(new_vertex);
    while ((*tree)->p != NULL)
    {
        (*tree) = (*tree)->p;
    }
    dump_tree_inorder("insert-2", *tree);
}

void *
find(struct vertex *v, int data)
{
    while (v != NULL && v->data != data)
        if (v->data < data)
            v = v->r;
        else
            v = v->l;

    return v;
}

static void
free_tree(struct vertex *root)
{
    if (root->l != NULL)
        free_tree(root->l);
    if (root->r != NULL)
        free_tree(root->r);

    free(root);
}

void
clear_tree(struct vertex **root)
{
    free_tree(*root);
    *root = NULL;
}
```

#### `avl2.c`

```
#include "AVL_tree.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct vertex *root = NULL;
    long sample[] = { 6, 2, 3 };
    enum { SIZE = sizeof(sample) / sizeof(sample[0]) };

    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
    {
        insert(&root, sample[j]);
    }

    clear_tree(&root);
    return(0);
}
```

#### Sample output

Again, run under `valgrind`, and I'm omitting about twenty lines of `valgrind` administrative output (nothing relevant):

```
-->> insert-1: (root 0x100AA94F0)
data 6; height 0; v = 0x100AA94F0, l = 0x000000000, r = 0x000000000, p = 0x000000000
<<-- insert-1:
-->> insert fixup 0: (root 0x100AA9560)
data 2; height 0; v = 0x100AA9560, l = 0x000000000, r = 0x000000000, p = 0x100AA94F0
<<-- insert fixup 0:
-->> insert fixup 3: (root 0x100AA94F0)
data 2; height 0; v = 0x100AA9560, l = 0x000000000, r = 0x000000000, p = 0x100AA94F0
data 6; height 1; v = 0x100AA94F0, l = 0x100AA9560, r = 0x000000000, p = 0x000000000
<<-- insert fixup 3:
-->> insert-2: (root 0x100AA94F0)
data 2; height 0; v = 0x100AA9560, l = 0x000000000, r = 0x000000000, p = 0x100AA94F0
data 6; height 1; v = 0x100AA94F0, l = 0x100AA9560, r = 0x000000000, p = 0x000000000
<<-- insert-2:
-->> insert fixup 0: (root 0x100AA95D0)
data 3; height 0; v = 0x100AA95D0, l = 0x000000000, r = 0x000000000, p = 0x100AA9560
<<-- insert fixup 0:
double left right rotating
-->> left_rotate: data 2; height 1; v = 0x100AA9560, l = 0x000000000, r = 0x100AA95D0, p = 0x100AA94F0
p is not NULL
p's l  == v
LR1 -  current node: data 2; height 1; v = 0x100AA9560, l = 0x000000000, r = 0x100AA95D0, p = 0x100AA94F0
LR1 -   parent node: data 6; height 2; v = 0x100AA94F0, l = 0x100AA9560, r = 0x000000000, p = 0x000000000
LR1 -  parent  left: data 2; height 1; v = 0x100AA9560, l = 0x000000000, r = 0x100AA95D0, p = 0x100AA94F0
LR1 - current right: data 3; height 0; v = 0x100AA95D0, l = 0x000000000, r = 0x000000000, p = 0x100AA9560
-->> LR1 - tree from parent: (root 0x100AA94F0)
data 2; height 1; v = 0x100AA9560, l = 0x000000000, r = 0x100AA95D0, p = 0x100AA94F0
data 3; height 0; v = 0x100AA95D0, l = 0x000000000, r = 0x000000000, p = 0x100AA9560
data 6; height 2; v = 0x100AA94F0, l = 0x100AA9560, r = 0x000000000, p = 0x000000000
<<-- LR1 - tree from parent:
Assign (*v)->r (0x100AA95D0) to (*v)->p->l (0x100AA9560)
LR2 -  current node: data 3; height 0; v = 0x100AA95D0, l = 0x000000000, r = 0x000000000, p = 0x100AA9560
LR2 -   parent node: data 2; height 1; v = 0x100AA9560, l = 0x000000000, r = 0x100AA95D0, p = 0x100AA94F0
LR2 -  parent  left: data  ; height  ; v = 0x000000000
LR2 - current right: data  ; height  ; v = 0x000000000
-->> LR2 - tree from parent: (root 0x100AA9560)
data 2; height 1; v = 0x100AA9560, l = 0x000000000, r = 0x100AA95D0, p = 0x100AA94F0
data 3; height 0; v = 0x100AA95D0, l = 0x000000000, r = 0x000000000, p = 0x100AA9560
<<-- LR2 - tree from parent:
get there before
r == NULL
Assertion failed: ((*v)->r != NULL), function left_rotate, file AVL_tree.c, line 156.
==47909== 
==47909== Process terminating with default action of signal 6 (SIGABRT)
==47909==    at 0x100318032: __pthread_sigmask (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib)
==47909==    by 0x100225774: __abort (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==47909==    by 0x1002256F5: abort (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==47909==    by 0x1001ECDF7: __assert_rtn (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==47909==    by 0x10000178A: left_rotate (AVL_tree.c:156)
==47909==    by 0x100001EAC: insert (AVL_tree.c:189)
==47909==    by 0x1000025B7: main (avl2.c:12)
```

What I think is relevant to the problem is the value of current node in the LR1 and LR2 output lines:

```
LR1 -  current node: data 2; height 1; v = 0x100AA9560, l = 0x000000000, r = 0x100AA95D0, p = 0x100AA94F0
…
LR2 -  current node: data 3; height 0; v = 0x100AA95D0, l = 0x000000000, r = 0x000000000, p = 0x100AA9560
```

Both of these are printing `*v`, but the node that it represents has changed.  Tracking down why that changed, and what to do about it, will probably resolve the problem.

Note the debugging techniques:

- Reduce the test case to a deterministic, non-interactive minimum.
- Have debug printing functions to print the data structures.
- Use assertions.
- Code around unexpected null pointers in the debug code. (For example, `dump_vertex()` originally had `assert(v != NULL)` but it fired when I didn't want it to, so now it handles null pointers.)

I'd often have the dump functions taking a `FILE *fp` argument so that they can be used to print to any file.  I'd also usually use `fflush(fp);` at the end of them to ensure the output is sent to the file stream, even if the program crashes abruptly afterwards.  Because I'm writing to standard output and it isn't redirected, it isn't causing trouble here — but it would be better to do it in the dumping code (and it would save me typing here, but you should know why it was done).

Comment: Thank you very much for such patient answer. My question is just why that line of code does not work as I want. after that line of code (*v)->r becomes a NULL which is not I expected, everything is crash. It only happen in double rotation in AVL tree. Thank you again!